# Cannot assign image in button in windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this error in my windows application. I have made build action " embedded resource and also make access modifier of image public. But still I am getting bellow error.

Please help me out with this error.

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure `OPDManagmentSystem.Properties.Resources.resources` was correctly embedded or linked into assembly `OPDManagmentSystem` at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: please show the code you are using to apply the image

Answer (score 0):

When I copied over files, and rebuilt a new VS2008 project, there was no hierarchical relationship in Visual Studio Solution Explorer for the resource file. For example, `ExceptionMessage.resx` and `ExceptionMessage.Designer.cs` were at the same level; whereas normally the `Designer.cs` file is indented under the `.resx` file.

So what I did was create a new `.resx file`, and carefully copy over using NotePad and filemerge programs, pieces of the `.resx file` and `.cs file`. Then it worked fine...